# How to remove this unwanted right margin?

Tags: html, css

I have tried all the available solutions on Stack Overflow. I have set body,html and other elements to margin 0 but still I don't know from where does this come from.

In fact I knew about white spaces but this has a different color altogether. Just check image for more details. I did not add code because I don't know which part of code I should add as this unwanted space is created from header to footer.

If you tell me then I will be more than happy to add some code.

[image]

Comment: How do you expect us to help? You have to show the markup or a jsfiddle demonstrating your issue. We cannot _guess_ you markup.

Comment: Thank you @arkascha for the time you took to answer. Anyways I got my answer

Comment: Oh, I did not answer at all. I only asked you to enhance your question so that people can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by CSS.

```
Overflow-x:hidden;
```

For example:

```
body{ 
    Overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: body{ Overflow-x:hidden;} will be more precise.

Comment: Thanks Hansie and Stark. It worked.